# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.testing.core.DummyCommandData

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

When trying to run test for CORDA the given Test case getting the following error. I am using JDK 1.8. Intellij IDEA.When trying to run test for CORDA the given Test case getting the following error. I am using JDK 1.8. Intellij IDEA.When trying to run test for CORDA the given Test case getting the following error. I am using JDK 1.8. Intellij IDEA.

MetalContract

```
package com.template.contracts;

import com.template.states.MetalState;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command;
import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandData;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Contract;
import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.List;

// ************
// * Contract *
// ************
public class MetalContract implements Contract {
    // This is used to identify our contract when building a transaction.
    public static final String CID = "com.template.contracts.MetalContract";
    
    // A transaction is valid if the verify() function of the contract of all the transaction's input and output states
    // does not throw an exception.
    @Override
    public void verify(@NotNull LedgerTransaction tx) throws IllegalArgumentException{

        if (tx.getCommands().size() != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Transaction must have one Command.");

        Command command = tx.getCommand(0);
        CommandData commandType = command.getValue();

        List<PublicKey> requiredSigners = command.getSigners();


        // -------------------------------- Issue Command Contract Rules ------------------------------------------


     if (commandType instanceof Issue) {
         // Issue transaction logic

         // Shape Rules

         if (tx.getInputs().size() != 0)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Issue cannot have inputs");

         if (tx.getOutputs().size() != 1)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Issue can only have one output");

         // Content Rules

         ContractState outputState = tx.getOutput(0);

         if (!(outputState instanceof MetalState))
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output must be a metal State");

         MetalState metalState = (MetalState) outputState;

         if (!metalState.getMetalName().equals("Gold")&&!metalState.getMetalName().equals("Silver")){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Metal is not Gold or Silver");
         }

         // Signer Rules

         Party issuer = metalState.getIssuer();
         PublicKey issuersKey = issuer.getOwningKey();

         if (!(requiredSigners.contains(issuersKey)))
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Issuer has to sign the issuance");

     }


        // -------------------------------- Transfer Command Contract Rules ------------------------------------------


       else if (commandType instanceof Transfer) {
            // Transfer transaction logic

            // Shape Rules

            if (tx.getInputs().size() != 1)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Transfer needs to have one input");

            if (tx.getOutputs().size() != 1)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Transfer can only have one output");

            // Content Rules

            ContractState inputState = tx.getInput(0);
            ContractState outputState = tx.getOutput(0);


            if (!(outputState instanceof MetalState))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output must be a metal State");

            MetalState metalState = (MetalState) inputState;

            if (!metalState.getMetalName().equals("Gold")&&!metalState.getMetalName().equals("Silver")){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Metal is not Gold or Silver");
            }

            // Signer Rules

            Party owner = metalState.getOwner();
            PublicKey ownersKey = owner.getOwningKey();

            if (!(requiredSigners.contains(ownersKey)))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Owner has to sign the transfer");



        }

       else  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised command.");




    }




    // Used to indicate the transaction's intent.
    public static class Issue implements CommandData {}
    public static class Transfer implements CommandData {}
}
```

ContractTests

```
package com.template.contracts;

import com.template.states.MetalState;
import com.template.contracts.MetalContract;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Contract;
import net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name;
import net.corda.testing.contracts.DummyState;
import net.corda.testing.core.DummyCommandData;
import net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity;
import net.corda.testing.node.MockServices;
import org.junit.Test;

import static net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.transaction;

public class ContractTests {

    private final TestIdentity Mint = new TestIdentity (new CordaX500Name ("mint", "", "GB"));
    private final TestIdentity TraderA = new TestIdentity (new CordaX500Name ("traderA", "", "GB"));
    private final TestIdentity TraderB = new TestIdentity (new CordaX500Name ("traderB", "", "GB"));


    private final MockServices ledgerServices = new MockServices();

    private MetalState metalState = new MetalState("Gold", 10, Mint.getParty(), TraderA.getParty());
    private MetalState metalStateInput = new MetalState("Gold", 10, Mint.getParty(), TraderA.getParty());
    private MetalState metalStateOutput = new MetalState("Gold", 10, Mint.getParty(), TraderB.getParty());

    @Test
    public void metalContractImplementsContract() {
        assert (new MetalContract() instanceof Contract);
    }
    @Test
    public void MetalContractRequiresTheTransactionCommandToBeATransferCommand() {

        transaction(ledgerServices, tx -> {
            // Has wrong command, will fail
            tx.input(MetalContract.CID, metalStateInput);
            tx.output(MetalContract.CID, metalStateOutput);
            tx.command(TraderA.getPublicKey(), DummyCommandData.INSTANCE);
            tx.fails();
            return null;
        });
   }
```

The Error is as following :

```
[WARN] 12:35:16,753 [main] contracts.AttachmentConstraint. - Found state com.template.contracts.MetalContract that is constrained by the insecure: AlwaysAcceptAttachmentConstraint.

net.corda.core.internal.TransactionDeserialisationException: Failed to deserialise group COMMANDS_GROUP at index 0 in transaction: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.testing.core.DummyCommandData

    at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt:82)
    at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt)
    at net.corda.core.internal.LazyMappedList.get(InternalUtils.kt:567)
    at net.corda.core.internal.LazyMappedList.get(InternalUtils.kt:567)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.createLtxForVerification(LedgerTransaction.kt:668)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.access$createLtxForVerification(LedgerTransaction.kt:44)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction$internalPrepareVerify$1.invoke(LedgerTransaction.kt:154)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction$internalPrepareVerify$1.invoke(LedgerTransaction.kt:44)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$1.invoke(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:345)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:344)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$default(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:319)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.internalPrepareVerify$core(LedgerTransaction.kt:146)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:136)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addMissingDependency(TransactionBuilder.kt:185)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:165)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core$default(TransactionBuilder.kt:133)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:130)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TestTransactionDSLInterpreter.toWireTransaction$test_utils(TestDSL.kt:131)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TestLedgerDSLInterpreter.recordTransactionWithTransactionMap(TestDSL.kt:298)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TestLedgerDSLInterpreter._unverifiedTransaction(TestDSL.kt:336)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TransactionDSL.input(TransactionDSLInterpreter.kt:150)
    at com.template.contracts.ContractTests.lambda$MetalContractRequiresTheTransactionCommandToBeATransferCommand$13(ContractTests.java:190)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils$transaction$1.invoke(NodeTestUtils.kt:54)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils$transaction$1.invoke(NodeTestUtils.kt)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils$ledger$2.invoke(NodeTestUtils.kt:39)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils$ledger$2.invoke(NodeTestUtils.kt)
    at net.corda.testing.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$withTestSerializationEnvIfNotSet$1.invoke(InternalTestUtils.kt:231)
    at net.corda.testing.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$withTestSerializationEnvIfNotSet$1.invoke(InternalTestUtils.kt)
    at net.corda.testing.common.internal.CommonSerializationTestHelpersKt.asContextEnv(CommonSerializationTestHelpers.kt:11)
    at net.corda.testing.internal.InternalSerializationTestHelpersKt.asTestContextEnv(InternalSerializationTestHelpers.kt:33)
    at net.corda.testing.internal.InternalSerializationTestHelpersKt.asTestContextEnv$default(InternalSerializationTestHelpers.kt:31)
    at net.corda.testing.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt.withTestSerializationEnvIfNotSet(InternalTestUtils.kt:231)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.ledger(NodeTestUtils.kt:36)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.transaction(NodeTestUtils.kt:53)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.transaction$default(NodeTestUtils.kt:51)
    at net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.transaction(NodeTestUtils.kt)
    at com.template.contracts.ContractTests.MetalContractRequiresTheTransactionCommandToBeATransferCommand(ContractTests.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.testing.core.DummyCommandData
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:106)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:119)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:145)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:73)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:85)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:105)
    at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt:78)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.corda.testing.core.DummyCommandData
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:523)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.TypeIdentifier$Unparameterised.getLocalType(TypeIdentifier.kt:151)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1$1.apply(TypeLoader.kt:38)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1$1.apply(TypeLoader.kt:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1.invoke(TypeLoader.kt:38)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1.invoke(TypeLoader.kt:25)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
    at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.putAll(Maps.kt:339)
    at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.toMap(Maps.kt:504)
    at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.toMap(Maps.kt:498)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader.load(TypeLoader.kt:45)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory.reflect(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:129)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory.access$reflect(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:47)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory$get$1.invoke(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:71)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory$get$1.invoke(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:47)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultDescriptorBasedSerializerRegistry.getOrBuild(DescriptorBasedSerializerRegistry.kt:28)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory.get(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:66)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposedSerializerFactory.get(SerializerFactory.kt)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject(DeserializationInput.kt:172)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull(DeserializationInput.kt:147)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput$deserialize$1.invoke(DeserializationInput.kt:124)
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:99)
    ... 74 more
```

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'

cordapp {
    targetPlatformVersion corda_platform_version
    minimumPlatformVersion corda_platform_version
    contract {
        name "Template CorDapp"
        vendor "Corda Open Source"
        licence "Apache License, Version 2.0"
        versionId 1
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main{
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            java.outputDir = file('bin/main')
        }
    }
    test{
        java{
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
            java.outputDir = file('bin/test')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Corda dependencies.
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"
    testCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
}
```

Comment: Could you check your Corda version from your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Added the build.gradle from contracts module

Comment: Could you check the actual version? This should be stated in the file `constants.properties`. Also, could you show how your contract is written exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem caused by your DummyCommandData.

The Command has to be defined inside your contract instead of creating another data class aside.

Try putting a command inside your contract.
ie.

```
public MetalContract extends Contract{

    public interface Commands extends CommandData {
        class Create implements Commands {}
    }
    //...
}
```